# Best way to use Python classes for creating Stripe objects and handling errors

Tags: python, django, oop, stripe-payments

I have a Django application that integrates with Stripe. Per the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling), I am following their recommendation to use try/except clauses to handle any errors that might arise during the process of creating customers, products, prices, etc.

To keep things DRY, I have made a base Python class from which object-specific subclasses inherit. This way I can customize the create_method of each subclass to create a particular object, but still keep all the error handling in one place (the parent class). This all seems to be working fine, but I'm wondering if anyone has any feedback or suggested improvements for this approach? Thanks!

```
import stripe

from django.conf import settings

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

class StripeObject():
    """
    Base class for all Stripe objects (e.g., Customer, Product, Price)
    """

    create_method = None

    def __init__(self, common_kwargs={}, instance_kwargs={}):
        self.common_kwargs = common_kwargs
        self.instance_kwargs = instance_kwargs

    def handle_error(self, e):
        try:
            print('Code is: %s' % e.code)
            print('Message is: %s' % e.user_message)
        except KeyError:
            print('One of the following keys was not found in the error response:\ncode or user_message.')

    def create(self):
        try:
            return self.create_method(**self.common_kwargs, **self.instance_kwargs)
        except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
            # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
            self.handle_error(e)
        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
            # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            self.handle_error(e)
        except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
            # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            self.handle_error(e)
        except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
            # Network communication with Stripe failed
            self.handle_error(e)
        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            # yourself an email
            self.handle_error(e)
        except Exception as e:
            # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            self.handle_error(e)

class StripeCustomer(StripeObject):
    create_method = stripe.Customer.create

class StripeProduct(StripeObject):
    create_method = stripe.Product.create

class StripePrice(StripeObject):
    create_method = stripe.Price.create

    def __init__(self, instance_kwargs):
        common_kwargs = {
            "currency": "usd"
        }
        super().__init__(common_kwargs=common_kwargs, instance_kwargs=instance_kwargs)
```

The resulting interface for these classes is:

```
product = StripeProduct({"name":"Product Name"}).create()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch only `stripe.error.StripeError` this except will catch all exception which extend `StripeError` (like `AuthenticationError`, `InvalidRequestError`, `RateLimitError` etc);

Others exception are not relate with Stripe package and there is not need to catch it.

Also using `except Exception` can catch all exceptions, but it is not good practice to use it because its too broad exception clause.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. Thanks!